# Excel SUMIFS function not returning results consistently

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a spreadsheet that I use to keep track of my checking account, budget and spending habits. I have a list of my financial transactions from my bank that I put in a table that looks like this (All dates and amounts are random):

[image: Budget Example]

I populate a budget chart and table that looks something like this:

[image: Budget Table]

[image: Budget Chart]

For awhile, I've been manually changing the fill of the Category tabs and manually populating the budget table. However, I realized that by adding conditional format rules that change the fill and text color based on specific text in a cell, I can add text like "Housing" or "Automotive" to the Category column and it would not only manually change the fill for me but it would also allow me to automatically populate the budget table. I tried using the `SUMIFS` function to do this.

Here's the way I tried to implement the `SUMIFS` function in the "Housing" cell for January in the Budget Table:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet 1'!$D$2:$D$1000, 'Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$1000, $A4, 'Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$1000, ">01/01/2016", 'Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$1000, "<01/31/2016")
```

This works for January and May, but when I use the same formula for February:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet 1'!$D$2:$D$1000, 'Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$1000, $A4, 'Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$1000, ">02/01/2016", 'Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$1000, "<02/29/2016")
```

It returns a value of `0`  to the column. It does this for all other months. Any idea why this formula might not be working for me?

**EDIT:** Incase my forumla wasn't clear, I wanted to provide a break down. The `SUMIFS` formula is supposed to be summing all values in the `Amount` column (the 2:1000 is to have enough of an area to look for that it will cover a year of my regular updates to this table without having to update the search area) that fall into the specified criteria. Those criteria being the text "Housing" being in the "Category" column (which is following the conditional formatting rules so fill and text color are changed) and the value falls into the range of dates provided.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `>` rather than `>=`. It seems like you're excluding the first and last day of the month? As a test, try adding in a column that just returns the month (`=MONTH(B2)`) and doing `SUMIF(month_column,2,D:D)`

Comment: @CallumDA33 Well, to my great shame... that was all it was lol. I'm not sure why I didn't use the `>=` or `<=` symbols but that was the issue.

Comment: No problem. I added as the answer so that you can accept and close. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing:

`<` with `<=` and `>` with `>=`

will bring your values into the correct range